# Plotly R legend with groupnames

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to create a graph in plotly where I group the legends but instead of appearing the trace names in the legend I would just have the group names appearing.

The code I have is the following:

```
p = plot_ly() %>%
  layout(
    font = list(family = "Arial"),
    legend = list(x = 0.07, y = 1))
p = add_trace(p,
              x = x, 
              y = y, 
              line = list(color = "blue", width=4),
              legendgroup = "Average",
              name = "Average",
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers"
)
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  p = add_trace(p,
              x = x, 
              y = df[,i],
              legendgroup = "Individual",
              line = list(color = "gray"),
              name = P_names[i],
              type = "scatter", 
              mode = "lines+markers"
              )
}
```

Ideally what I want is a legend box with only: "Average" and "Individual". Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: you should provide data

Comment: Thanks for your response. It can be any general data. I have the df of curves with curve1, 2, 3 and this is under "Individual" and the average of the individual curves makes the "Average".